# How to open a vpn channel (interactively) and keep the vpn session in background

Tags: linux, vpn, shell

*[Archlinux 4.18.9]*

I have built a straightforward alias to connect to a cluster via vpn:

```
alias clusvpn='sudo /usr/bin/openvpn --config client.ovpn'
```

This include a specific `/etc/sudoers` entry so no sudo password is requested from the authorized users, upon issuing the cmd.

This leads to 2 input requests: one for the registered users' name on the distant vpn server, one for the users' password. By hand, from cli, everything works just as it should. No issue.

However **I'd like to place my vpn session in the background automatically, once the channel is open, i.e. once the users have entered their name and passwd.** Ideally I want to signify that fact at the same time the cmd is issued using the alias. But issuing `sudo /usr/bin/openvpn --config client.ovpn &` just does not allow users to input their username and password.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to file containing password and username ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the credentials you're talking about you could pass with `--auth-user-pass`, not with `--askpass`, so `--daemon` is not useful.

I think you can use [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). A sketch of a possible solution:

1. `spawn sudo /usr/bin/openvpn --config client.ovpn` to run the program.
2. `expect "Username: "` or similar (depending on what `openvpn` prints, I cannot check this right now) to wait for the prompt.
3. Use a code like:

   ```
   send_user "Username: "
   expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
   ```

   to get username from the user.
4. `send "$expect_out(1,string)\n"` to pass it to the program.
5. Repeat with password, `stty -echo` may be useful.
6. At the end use `fork` and `disconnect` to put the program into the background.

There are examples in the manual that may help you. I think you can even implement some logic to cover responses like "invalid password, try again" etc.

---

This is my *not-quite-tested* piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

log_user 0
set timeout -1

spawn sudo /usr/bin/openvpn --config client.ovpn

expect "*sername*"
send_user "Username: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send "$expect_out(1,string)\n"

expect "*assword*"
stty -echo
send_user "Password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send "$expect_out(1,string)\n"
stty echo

send_user "\n"

if {[fork]!=0} exit
disconnect
expect eof
```

The only testing was on Debian with `spawn nc …` that connected to another `nc` listening in a separate console. I sent prompts and answers successfully, then the original `expect` terminated. I was at the shell prompt, but the two `nc`-s were still connected, the spawned one was running in the background. The same should happen to `openvpn`, I have never tested this with `openvpn` though.

Please take it from here (hint: commenting the line `log_user 0` out is useful for testing).

Comment: I had been playing with `--auth-user-pass` and `--daemon` with very limited success (obviously since a file written to disk and containing credentials is involved). I will give an honest try to your suggestions next weekend and will report here. Thank you.

Comment: +1 after 2 and some years. I wish I had known `expect` back when I used "kermit" on a pair of Zyxel 14.4kbps (yes, 14.4k !) modems to connect to distant mainframes, paying for the call everytime to check on batch jobs during the weekend ... Oh ! and, if I recall well, in the end I did not use `expect` with `openvpn` because "someone" changed my cluster access to a bastion which adds yet another layer of `ssh`'ing to get to my coveted cloud console. Tx in any case.